flush_dcache_pages() and dma_map_[single | sg ] perform the same functionality?
I am writing a dma driver which can take the userspace buffers for source / destination. The pages from userspace are mapped using the get_user_pages_fast(). I got flush_dcache_pages() to clear any stale data cache with the pinned pages. I am creating a scatter-gather list out of these pages and doing a dma_map_sg() of the received list of the pinned pages. Does the dma_map_sg() also clears the data cache of the pinned pages as done by the flush_dcache_pages()?
The query comes from the code of the dma_map_sg()
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.8.8/source/kernel/dma/direct.h#L112
if (!dev_is_dma_coherent(dev) && !(attrs & DMA_ATTR_SKIP_CPU_SYNC)) arch_sync_dma_for_device(phys, size, dir);
Does the pointed out code and flush_dcache_pages() achieve the same functionality?
If yes, then flush_dcache_pages() may not be required.
Till now, I haven't tried removing the flush_dcache_page(), due to some limitations.
